# WPF returning a List to the class

Tags: c#, wpf

New to WPF and C# from VB web forms, so sorry for this poorly structured question I will add to as needed to improve. I am trying to implement an example by adding database calls to MySQL to populate an On-Demand Tree View control. Here is the link to the sample code...

[sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode)

Got my db connection working and data is populating my dataset. I iterate to place in a List. But can not seem to figure out the issue with passing the List to the Class to populate the control...

```
public class Level1
{
    public Level1(string level1Name)
    {
        this.Level1Name = level1Name;
    }

    public string Level1Name { get; private set; }

    readonly List<Level2> _level2s = new List<Level2>();
    public List<Level2> Level2s
    {
        get { return _level2s; }
    }
}
```

I have a database class that queries the db and parses the data....

```
List<string> level1s = new List<string>();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        level1s.Add((string)row["name"]);
    }
}


**UPDATE**: Trying to return the list...

return new Level1[]
  {
  foreach(DataRow row in level1s)
  {
    // iterate here               
  }
};
```

My level1s List is properly populated, I am just drawing a blank on returning the values.

thanks,

**UPDATE** - I am including the ViewModel code here as well....

```
using BusinessLib;

namespace TreeViewWithViewModelTOC.LoadOnDemand
{
    public class Level1ViewModel : TreeViewItemViewModel
    {
        readonly Level1 _level1;

        public Level1ViewModel(Level1 level1) 
            : base(null, true)
        {
            _level1 = level1;
        }

        public string Level1Name
        {
            get { return _level1.Level1Name; }
        }

        protected override void LoadChildren()
        {
            foreach (Level2 level2 in Database.GetLevel2s(_level1))
                base.Children.Add(new Level2ViewModel(level2, this));
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Good question, spinning my wheels. I did not want to change the Level1 class so I have tried to iterate over level1s by adding them to LEvel1[ ]. I could not get that to work, I also tried calling the class on each iteration which I knew was wrong but wanted try something. C# is my weak spot here.

Comment: create the `instance` of `Level1`, `Iterate` thru `level1s` and add each item to `Level1`, Why is `Level2s` is `readonly/ only get` ?

Comment: I tried this but I am getting and error.           
            return new Level1[]
            {
                foreach(DataRow row in level1s)
                {
                      // add to Level1        
                }
       
      
           
            };     foreach is an invalid expression.

Comment: foreach is an invalid expression. Updated original post.

Comment: ok. First create a `List<Level1>`  then add each item in your `level1s` to a new `Level1` and add to the list then `return` the `List`.

Comment: What is the recommended approach to iterate if the foreach throws this error?

Comment: returning the values? for what? make sure you read up on MVVM, this is trivial to mvvm followers.

Comment: @Netscape Well that is what I am trying to learn here and from the demo, just having issues trying to return the data from the database query to the control, as would typically be done and as noted in the comments of the demo in the database.cs file or BusinesLib project. Just looking for a little help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this below,

> ```
> List<Level1> L1=new List<Level1>();
>  foreach(var row in level1s)
>  {
>     Level1 L=new Level1();
>     // L.Level1Name = row.ToString(); here add items as you need
>     L1.Add(L);
>   }
>  return L1.ToArray();
> ```

Comment: Cannot Convert Type 'string' to System.Data.DataRow.

Comment: Check Now, i have edited the answer. `Level1` is a `list` of `string` so you can add it with out converting it.

Comment: sorry internet went out, Level1 L = new Level1();  throws error: Level1 does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: and return L1;  errors says: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BusinessLib.Level1>' to BusinessLib.Level1[]

Comment: Convert the List to Array, Edited the answer check it.

Comment: Thats fine this is how you can learn. I suggest you to understand C# basics, Then WPF bindings, Then go for MVVM.

Comment: Exactly the path I have been pursuing, demand for C#  on this project is strong. thanks again.

Comment: @htm11h This snippet doesn't really get you anywhere and deviates from the intent of the sample code tutorial by Josh Smith.  The `LoadChildren` function is in the ViewModel, so you should properly be adding/modifying the `_children` `ObservableCollection` in the view model so it updates your UI directly rather than returning the children to some outside entity.

Comment: I was under the impression his intent was to separate Bus Logic from process. I will look into your suggestion. Since the calls were being made on demand it seemed practical to have the DB calls moved out to their own class.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using MVVM design pattern to solve this.  There aren't many requirements listed in your questions so I will assume my own, which should lead you along the right path.

First thing is determining whether or not you're records are going to be ready/pulled at run-time--before the `TreeView` is rendered and if they will be changed/updated/added/removed from the structure during the lifecycle of the application.  If the structure isn't going to be changed, you can continue to use `List` as your collection.  If you're (or a user is) going to be adding/removing from the collection, ultimately changing the structure, then you need to notify the UI that a change occurred on the collection; so you would use the built in [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) for that.  Here is a MVVM-purist solution, with the assumption that your data will be pulled at application startup and you will be modifying the collection:

**Note**: `RelayCommand` implementation was taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

### Models

```
public class First
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public readonly List<Second> Children;

    public First(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Children = new List<Second>
        {
            new Second(1),
            new Second(2),
            new Second(3),
        };
    }

    public void AddChild(Second child)
    {
        Children.Add(child);
        ChildAdded(this, new ChildAddedEventArgs(child));
    }

    public EventHandler<ChildAddedEventArgs> ChildAdded;
}
```

---

```
public class ChildAddedEventArgs //technically, not considered a model
{
    public readonly Second ChildAdded;
    public ChildAddedEventArgs(Second childAdded)
    {
        ChildAdded = childAdded;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Second
{
    public int Number
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Second(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

### ViewModels

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<FirstViewModel> _items;
    private readonly ICommand _addFirstFirstChildCommand;
    private readonly ICommand _addSecondFirstChildCommand;
    private readonly ICommand _toggleExpandCollapseCommand;

    private bool _firstAddedFlag;

    public MainViewModel(IEnumerable<First> records)
    {
        _items = new ObservableCollection<FirstViewModel>();
        foreach(var r in records)
        {
            _items.Add(new FirstViewModel(r));
        }

        _addFirstFirstChildCommand = new RelayCommand(param => AddFirst(), param => CanAddFirst);
        _addSecondFirstChildCommand = new RelayCommand(param => AddSecond(), param => CanAddSecond);
        _toggleExpandCollapseCommand = new RelayCommand(param => ExpandCollapseAll(), param =>
        {
            return true;
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FirstViewModel> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddFirstFirstChildCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _addFirstFirstChildCommand;
        }
    }
    public ICommand AddSecondFirstChildCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _addSecondFirstChildCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand ToggleExpandCollapseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _toggleExpandCollapseCommand;
        }
    }
    public bool CanAddFirst
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool CanAddSecond
    {
        get
        {
            //Only allow second to be added if we added to first, first
            return _firstAddedFlag;
        }
    }

    public void AddFirstChild(FirstViewModel item)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
    }

    private void AddFirst()
    {
        _items[0].AddChild(new Second(10));
        _firstAddedFlag = true;
    }

    private void AddSecond()
    {
        _items[1].AddChild(new Second(20));
    }

    private void ExpandCollapseAll()
    {
        foreach(var i in Items)
        {
            i.IsExpanded = !i.IsExpanded;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FirstViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly First model;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<SecondViewModel> _children;

    private bool _isExpanded;

    public FirstViewModel(First first)
    {
        _children = new ObservableCollection<SecondViewModel>();
        model = first;
        foreach(var s in first.Children)
        {
            Children.Add(new SecondViewModel(s));
        }
        model.ChildAdded += OnChildAdded;
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return model.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            model.Name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SecondViewModel> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _children;
        }
    }

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get
        {
            return _isExpanded;
        }
        set
        {
            _isExpanded = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    internal void AddChild(Second second)
    {
        model.AddChild(second);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void OnChildAdded(object sender, ChildAddedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(Children != null)
        {
            Children.Add(new SecondViewModel(args.ChildAdded));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SecondViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Second model;
    private bool _isExpanded;

    public SecondViewModel(Second second)
    {
        model = second;
    }
    public int SecondNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return model.Number;
        }
        set
        {
            model.Number = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    //Added property to avoid warnings in output window
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get
        {
            return _isExpanded;
        }
        set
        {
            _isExpanded = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

### Model Provider

```
public class Database
{
    public static IEnumerable<First> GetChildren()
    {
        List<First> firsts = new List<First>();
        firsts.Add(new First("John"));
        firsts.Add(new First("Roxanne"));
        return firsts;
    }
}
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainViewModel mvm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        var db = Database.GetChildren();
        mvm = new MainViewModel(db);
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = mvm;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do not do this, example only
        var f = new First("Billy");
        mvm.AddFirstChild(new FirstViewModel(f));

        //Prove that the event was raised in First, FirstViewModel see & handles it, and
        //the UI is updated
        f.AddChild(new Second(int.MaxValue));
    }
}
```

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FirstViewModel}" 
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SecondViewModel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondNumber}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
                            Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Add Child to first First"
                        Command="{Binding AddFirstFirstChildCommand}" />
                <Button Content="Toggle Expand"
                        Command="{Binding ToggleExpandCollapseCommand}" />
                <Button Content="Add Child to second First"
                        Command="{Binding AddSecondFirstChildCommand}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Bad Codebehind Button" 
                    Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, I will review it thoroughly as I move forward. There is no intent to require CRUD operations on the data, this is simply a table of contents treeview with load on demand as the sub categories are selected.

Comment: @html11h In that case, I'd have an IsSelected binding in `FirstViewModel`.  When that setter is hit and set to `True`, you would do `Items.Clear(); var lvl1items = Database.FindChildren(this.model.Name); foreach(var r in lvl1items) { Items.Add(new SecondViewModel(r)); }` or something of the sort

Comment: @htm11h not to mention, this is complete and pure MVVM; something that will only benefit you if you do it properly from the beginning. If I had to maintain the code found in the answer you used, I'd absolutely lose it.  If anything, change the function so that it returns `IEnumerable<Level1>` and get rid of the `ToArray`.

Comment: Thanks I will investigate this more. I need to update the code now that it is working as I am trying to stick to MVVM, but the control will eventually be handed of, more than likely as a dll

Answer (score 1):

this returns array of Level1 from first table in DataSet (usually there's only one table)

```
public void Level1[] GetLevels()
{
   DataSet ds = ....
   return ds.Tables[0].Rows
       .Select(row => new Level1((string)row["name"]))
       .ToArray();
}
```

if you had more than one table in the dataset, you can use this method to loop trough all tables:

```
public void Level1[] GetLevels()
{
   DataSet ds = ....
   return ds.Tables
       .SelectMany(t => t.Rows)
       .Select(row => new Level1((string)row["name"]))
       .ToArray();
}
```

The second code sample does exactly the same as your code in the question.

Understanding linq is extremely useful.